# Android Camera2 API send stream buffer to native function

Tags: android, java-native-interface, android-camera2

I'm trying to understand how to handle video and audio streams, get frames data into Buffer. I want to work with these buffers in native JNI function. This code is preparing video and audio to write into mp4 file. What should I use to write into buffer?

```
...
private void setUpMediaRecorder() throws IOException {
    final Activity activity = getActivity();
    if (null == activity) {
        return;
    }
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    if (mNextVideoAbsolutePath == null || mNextVideoAbsolutePath.isEmpty()) {
        mNextVideoAbsolutePath = getVideoFilePath(getActivity());
    }
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(mNextVideoAbsolutePath);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(10000000);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(mVideoSize.getWidth(), mVideoSize.getHeight());
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
    int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    switch (mSensorOrientation) {
        case SENSOR_ORIENTATION_DEFAULT_DEGREES:
            mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(DEFAULT_ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));
            break;
        case SENSOR_ORIENTATION_INVERSE_DEGREES:
            mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(INVERSE_ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));
            break;
    }
    mMediaRecorder.prepare();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear what kinds of buffers you want to read, but most likely you want an [ImageReader](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ImageReader.html).

You can set it up with ImageFormat.YUV_420_888 and use the Surface from with with a CameraDevice.  It'll then produce Image objects, which will have 3 Planes, each of which will have a ByteBuffer.  You can pass the ByteBuffer via JNI and access it with no copies using the ByteBuffer JNI methods.

Be sure to look at the row and pixel stride documented for each Plane, for correctly accessing the ByteBuffer data.

Comment: So, I can get three planes for every frame using ImageReader? The name 'Image' is confusing me, I thought it's only for pictures..

Comment: Yes, you get a Y, U, and V plane ByteBuffers.   'Image' is a pretty generic term, so I wouldn't attach much meaning to it; it's much the same as 'buffer', 'picture', 'frame', and so on.